# Want to create a new list by grouping the other list of objects by attribute

Tags: java, list, grouping

Want to create a list by grouping the other list of objects by attribute
Code is like this:

```
public class MyDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Data("NEW",todayDate,todayDatePlus1,"N"));
        list.add(new Data("AUTORIZED",todayDate,todayDatePlus1,"Y"));
        list.add(new Data("AUTORIZED",todayDatePlus1,todayDatePlus3,"Y"));
        list.add(new Data("AUTHENTICATE",todayDate,todayDatePlus1,"Y"));
        list.add(new Data("AUTHENTICATE",todayDatePlus1,todayDatePlus2,"Y"));
        list.add(new Data("COMPLETED",todayDate,todayDatePlus1,"N"));

    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
class Data{
    String phase;
    LocalDate startDate;
    LocalDate endDate;
    String required;
    
    Data(String phase,  LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, String required) {
        this.phase = phase;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.required = required;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
In New List 

("NEW",todayDate,todayDatePlus1,"N")
**("AUTORIZED",todayDate,todayDatePlus3,"Y")**
**("AUTHENTICATE",todayDate,todayDatePlus2,"Y")**
("COMPLETED",todayDate,todayDatePlus1,"N")
```

In the new list repeated attribute phase is combined as 1 and also StartDate's and EndDate's are updated. (StartDate Earlist one and EndDate as last one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Collectors.toMap with `mergefunction`, to merge the values of `Data` object having same `phase`

```
 Collection<Data> result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getPhase, Function.identity(), ((existing, replacement) -> {

                // Merge values of replacement with existing
                existing.setEndDate(replacement.getEndDate());
                return existing;
            }))).values();
```

Comment: Thank you, it's work for me, I have updated few lines to decide the correct start and end date.
In case when dates are mixed up.
                        if(!existing.getStartDate().isBefore(replacement.getStartDate())) {
               existing.setStartDate(replacement.getStartDate());
              }
              
              if(existing.getEndDate().isBefore(replacement.getEndDate())) {
               existing.setEndDate(replacement.getEndDate());
              }